# Service call from Android to cpp service

Tags: ros, c++, tutorial, service, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this tutorial /ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv and want to call the server from Android now, but can't find any hints how to accomplish this step by step.

My main problem is (i think) that i don't have the message structures in java, it's only built for cpp/python.

Can i dynamically create messages in Java without needing the type definitions? Or do i need to tweak something to get the Java definitions from my existing cpp/msg tutorial code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133696/service-call-from-android-to-cpp-service/) by [ruderik](https://answers.ros.org/users/12146/ruderik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosjava message generator is not yet native, so that's why you'll only find cpp/python (and sometimes lisp).

If you just want to use messages from officially released packages, then you can pull them from our [rosjava maven repo](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo) or if you want to build messages from your own custom message stacks, then check out the instructions in the [rosjava wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava). Not being a native generator, it's a bit complicated, but my team does it successfully like this at Yujin for a fairly large set of custom messages. They're neither experts at ros or java, but are quite comfortable with the process now.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruderik](https://answers.ros.org/users/12146/ruderik/) on 2014-02-27**:
Thanks for your answer and putting me on the right track. I'll try it out following this tutorial /rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Unofficial Messages (i'm not allowed to post actual links, sorry).